# Dynamic button creation for ListView

Tags: android, button, layout

I have a ListView that is used to display rows with data in them. Each row is supposed to have a button. When that button is clicked it is supposed to launch a query with data related to the row. However, I am having trouble getting the button to show up. If I define the button in the layout file it shows but I would start to run into issues with every button having the exact same ID. If I create the buttons dynamically, they either don't show up or mess up my layout.

EDIT:
This is my code used to create buttons dynamically:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.button_container);
LayoutParams params = ll.getLayoutParams();
btn = new Button(this);
btn.setText("Check in");
btn.setId(i);
ll.addView(btn);
params.height=LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
params.width=LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
ll.setLayoutParams(params);
btn.setTag(mGoalIds[i]);
btn.setOnClickListener(mButtonListener);
```

EDIT2: Managed to work around it by replacing the button with an OnItemClickListener.

Comment: Add some relevant code, please.

Comment: implement your click listener inside the `getView` of your adapter

Comment: I'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter in order to populate my list. Am I supposed to override the getView method of that?

Answer (score 0):

First implementation is goodin which you should define button in xml layout file.

Now your question i how to detect which row button is clicked at run time as all the buttons have same id.

Solution ->

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // ...........................
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String getSelectedItem = yourArrayList.get(position);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```